# Is it possible to set different camera parameters for front and back camera?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I was wondering if it's possible to set different camera parameters for front and back camera. If so, how to do it? If not, I was wondering if there was another solution for crashing when a device does not have one of the set parameters available, such as FLASH_MODE_ON or SCENE_HDR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this to test support:

```
Parameters params = null;
if(mCamera != null) {
    params = mCamera.getParameters();

    if(params != null) {
        List<String> supportedFlashModes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();

        if(supportedFlashModes != null) {
           if(supportedFlashModes.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH)) {
              params.setFlashMode( Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH );
         } else if(supportedFlashModes.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON)) {
              params.setFlashMode( Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON );
         } else {}//no support for flash etc
    }
}
```